# Convert Value on Realm Property When Retrieved and Saved in SwiftUI

Tags: swift, swiftui, realm, combine

I have a `Flight` Realm class with a `duration` property that is an `Int`. It stores the duration of a flight as the number of minutes.

```
class Flight: Object, ObjectKeyIdentifiable{
  @objc dynamic var duration = 0
}
```

I pass a `Flight` object as an `ObservedRealmObject` to a child view where it's edited. The user can enter the time as `HHMM` (130 = 1 hr 30 min) or `#.#` (1.5 hrs). I have some extensions that convert either of those times from a `String` to the number of minutes stored as an `Int` and back again.

But the problem I'm having is binding my `TextField`. I can't bind to the `duration` property directly because I need to convert it from the time format to the number of minutes.

```
struct MyView: View {
  @ObservedRealmObject var flight: Flight
  @AppStorage("timeDisplayHHMM") var timeDisplayHHMM = false
  
  var body: some View{
    TextField(timeDisplayHHMM ? "HHMM": "#.#", text: $flight.duration)
  }
}
```

I've tried a couple different approaches that don't quite work right.

### Attempt 1

I created a `@State` variable which I set in `.onAppear` and then I save the value inside `.onChange` like this:

```
@State var duration = ""

TextField(...)
  .onChange(of: duration, perform: { value in
    //Save duration using my view model
    model.saveDuration(flight: $flight, duration: duration)
  })
  .onAppear(){
    //Get value
    duration = flight.duration.timeDisplay //"timeDisplay" is my conversion Int extension.
  }
```

This works great, but it relies on `onAppear` to keep its value updated. So if the `duration` changes in my Realm, the UI won't update unless the user causes the view to appear again.

### Attempt 2

I've tried creating a custom binding and I set the binding's value from the Realm property, and then save it in the setter. This behaves erratically as the user types because the value is saved and updated before they can finish typing.

For example, if they type `1.` then it quickly saves it as 1 hour and then the value updates to `1.0` before they can finish typing `1.5`.

```
private var durationBinding: Binding<String> {
  Binding<String>(get: {
    //Set binding value
    flight.duration.timeDisplay
  }, set: {
    //Save
    model.saveDuration(flight: $flight, duration: $0)
  })
}
```

How can I get the benefits of binding to a `String` Realm property while still having the value convert to/from an `Int`?

Comment: For clarification, do you want to write data to Realm *as the user types* or do they type something and then you want to save it upon completion?

Comment: Ideally it would be as they type. My time conversion function returns `0` if they type invalid characters, so it should work that way.

Comment: I would suggest a different interface. It appears you have a master->slave situation with your viewControllers. When you display the slave controller (which is where the user enters the data) what if they type something, forget what was there and then changes their mind? They would have no way to get back what was there. I would suggest adding a save and cancel button so if that's the situation, they can cancel and return to the master viewController. That would avoid this issue entirely since it's only saved when the user wants to save it.